`.is_in_group` method not returning `true` despite being used on an object inside the specified group
I'm making a roguelike game in there is a large, procedurally generated level. There are loads of enemies in the level, and in this case they will only be aggravated and start attacking once you get within a certain range of them.
So to do this, I create a CollisionShape2D in the main scene. I name it 'AggravationRange', and I put it in the group 'AggrivationRangeGroup'. I then also add a Sprite2D as a child, so that I can see how large the parent CollisionShape2D is whilst inside the game. Then, right after I add the player to the main scene, I create a variable referencing the player node, then making it so that AggravationRange is always at the same position as the player. I do this instead of simply adding AggravationRange as a child to the player, as it prevents the rotation being changed also.
Next, I open the script for the enemy and add an _on_area_entered() signal. The code I use for it:
var PlayerDetected
_on_Enemy_area_entered(area):
   if area.is_in_group('AggravationRangeGroup'):
      PlayerDetected = true
      print('The enemy has been aggravated')

So then I load the game, and nothing ever prints to the console, despite the enemy is clearly within the CollisionShape2D.
I've placed another print() statement inside the _on_area_entered() signal, such that it would print whenever any area collides with it, and it works, so there's no problem with it detecting collisions, but just checking if the area is in a specified group seems the problem. I know it can't be it detecting a different CollisionShape2D, as there are only 2 CollisionShape2D's, the AggravationRange and the enemies hitbox.
So why doesn't it detect the area being in the group? It's spelt correctly, monitorable is set to true, and I can't find any issues with the code.

Just to be clear: You added an Area2D to your main scene, which holds a collision shape right? And just to be sure: Did you add the area to the group or as you have written the collision shape?

@Bugfish No. The main scene held the CollisionShape2D, and when I instance the player scene and add it as a child of the root node of the main scene. I've tried adding the CollisionShape2D to the group, I've tried giving it an empty Area2D parent and adding that, but it doesn't work.

Fixed by checking area.name instead of using area.is_in_group().
